# What does it mean Offline support (7 day validity) in apple provision profile?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

When I tried to create iOS development provision profile I saw check box "Offline support (7 day validity)" Yes / No

What does it mean?

Comment: You "saw" it where?

Answer (score 0):

This option means that you can build and run application at device with disabled internet.
If you switched this option off, you will see app verifictaion error, when you run app at real device.